# Sort ArrayList using its mediana value

Tags: java, sorting

I have an ArrayList of Integer amd method that calculates its mediana.

```
public Integer caclucateMediana(){
    //some calculations
...
}
```

1. START {0,1,2,3,4} --> mediana is 2. Put it to the beginninh of the String "2"
2. {0,1,3,4} are left. Mediana here is 1. Put it to the String "2 1"
3. {0,3,4} are left. Mediana here is 3. Put it to the String "2 1 3"
4. {0,4} are left. Mediana here is 0. Put it to the String "2 1 3 0"
5. Only {4} is left in array. Put it to the result String "2 1 3 0 4"

I'm trying to implement method SortByMediana and use the recursion, but not sure if it's the correct solution.

```
public String sortByMediana (){
        int mediana = 0;
        String result = "";

        ArrayList list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (Integer number : this) {
            list.add(number);
        }

        result = recMethod(list);
        return result;
    }

    public String recMethod (ArrayList<Integer> list)
    {
        int mediana = 0;
        String result = "";

        if (list.size() > 0){
            mediana =  caclucateMediana();
            ArrayList<Integer> newList = (ArrayList<Integer>)list.clone();

            newList.remove((Object) mediana);
            result += recMethod(newList);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Any ideas how to sort ListArray with this method and return String with the result?

Comment: I'm not sure you'd need recursion here. Could you elaborate a little on how sorting should happen? From your example I would assume this: 1) calculate the median, e.g. 2 in your example, 2) sort the array by distance from median value while keeping lower numbers first, so in your example you'd get: `2 (0), 1 (-1), 3(1), 0 (-2), 4 (2)`  (where the format is `value (distance from median)`). Is that correct? If so you'd just need an appropriate comparator. Building a string out of the list would then be the easiest part.

Comment: How do you get for the list `0, 1, 2, 3, 4.` with a median `2` to the result `2, 1, 3, 0, 4` ?

Comment: I can write by steps to make it clear
1) START {0,1,2,3,4} --> mediana is 2. Put it to the beginninh of the String "2"
2) {0,1,3,4} are left. Mediana here is 1. Put it to the String "2 1"
3) {0,3,4} are left. Mediana here is 3. Put it to the String "2 1 3"
4) {0,4} are left. Mediana here is 0. Put it to the String "2 1 3 0"
5) Onle {4} is left in array. Put it to the result String "2 1 3 0 4"

Comment: Well, in that case a simple loop should be sufficient. Just take the element at `(list.size()-1)/2` (look at `get(index)` and `remove(index)`) until the list is empty. That way you should get 2 at index 2 (5-1/2 = 2), then 1 at index 1 (4-1/2 = 1), 3 at index 1 (3-1/2 = 1), 0 at index 0 (2-1/2 = 0) and 4 at index 0 (1-1/2 = 0).

Comment: One question: do you expect duplicate values in your lists and if so would those be sorted or potentially unordered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach without recursion (assuming that your method `calculateMediana` actually takes the `List<Integer>` in entry and returns the median `Integer`):

```
public String sortByMediana(List<Integer> list) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    List<Integer> analyzed = new ArrayList<>(list);
    while (!analyzed.isEmpty()) {
        Integer mediana = calculateMediana(analyzed);
        builder.add(mediana).add(" ");
        analyzed.remove(analyzed.indexOf(mediana));
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Explanation:

- Start with a list `analyzed` which is a copy of the input list
- Get the mediana using your function `calculateMediana`
- Add it to the string you want to return and remove it from the list `analyzed`
- Repeat this process until when the list is empty

Comment: I need to use these two methods: CalculateMediana() and SortByMediana using objects, like analyzed.calculateMediana() and list.SortByMediana(). So these methods don't have any parameters. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: @EkaterinaKhudzhamkulova in that case it's just about wrapping the standard java list inside a custom object, and the methods without parameters will be called on your custom object (that will handle redirecting the call on the list held internally)

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in my comment, a simple loop should do. Since the median is the center element of a collection we can define its zero-based index as `collection.size()-1/2` (indices range from 0 to size()-1).

Due to integer math this also takes care of selecting the left element of the center pair in a collection of even length, e.g. in `[0, 1, 3, 4]` you want to select 1 which is at index 1. Thus `4-1 = 3` and `3/2 = 1` takes care of this.

Thus building the result could be as simple as:

```
//copy the original list to keep it untouched
List<Integer> listCopy = new ArrayList<>(list); 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while(!listCopy.isEmpty()) {
  //append a space if we already have content
  if( sb.length() > 0) {
    sb.append(" ");
  }

  //calculate the index (see above)
  int medianIndex = listCopy.size() - 1 / 2;
  //get the median and remove it from the list
  Integer median = listCopy.remove(medianIndex);
  //append the median to the string builder
  sb.append(median);
}

String result = sb.toString();
```